# What is Gradle's equivalent to Ant Java Task?

Tags: java, gradle, ant

The [Ant Java Task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) helps to execute a Java class with options to fork and others.
I want to achieve similar behaviour with Gradle. A few things to note, I only want to use the `java` plugin and not `application` and `java-library`, I don't want to use `ant` within Gradle. I'm curious on how to achieve this with base `java` plugin and gradle tasks.

I'm looking for something similar to

```
task runClass {
  dependsOn build
  java('com.example.Main', args={}, fork=true, options={})
}
```

update: I was able to start a forked JVM instance with target class and args using [JavaExec](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html). I'm blocked on trying to run this as a background process, instead of blocking the task workflow.

```
task run(type: JavaExec) {
  dependsOn build
  classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
  main = 'org.example.Main'
  args 'hello'
  maxHeapSize '512m'
}
```

Comment: *"I want to use the `java` plugin"* So read the **manual**, which tells you all about how to use it: [The Java Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html). Click the [JavaCompile](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.html) link to see compiler options.

Comment: Your question is all over the place.  Start a new SPECIFIC FOCUSED question.

Comment: @jnovack, My question boils down to what is ANT's Java task equivalent in Gradle, without using the ANT wrapper provided.